# Remove first object from json on checkbox click - AngularJs + NodeJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, node.js

This is my JSON object:

```
[
   { 
      field1: 'gsm',
      field2: 'firstname',
      field3: 'lastname',
      field4: 'street',
      field5: 'city',
      field6: 'region',
      field7: 'postcode',
      field8: 'dob',
      field9: 'email',
      field10: 'company',
      field11: 'url',
      field12: 'country',
      field13: 'data1',
      field14: 'data2',
      field15: 'data3' 
   },

   { 
      field1: '123456789',
      field2: 'Mohamed',
      field3: 'Sameer',
      field4: 'Salai',
      field5: 'Salai',
      field6: 'Asia',
      field7: '111111',
      field8: '10-10-10',
      field9: 'mohd@if.com',
      field10: 'ifelse',
      field11: 'ifelse',
      field12: 'India',
      field13: 'test',
      field14: 'test',
      field15: 'test' 
   },
   { 
      field1: '123456789',
      field2: 'Hameed',
      field3: 'Basha',
      field4: 'Salai',
      field5: 'Salai',
      field6: 'Asia',
      field7: '600091',
      field8: '10-10-10',
      field9: 'hameed@gmail',
      field10: 'ifelse',
      field11: 'ifelse',
      field12: 'India',
      field13: 'test',
      field14: 'test',
      field15: 'test' 
   }
]
```

I have this json object i am displaying this json to client side using ng-repeat function with the help of angularjs.

I have one checkbox and one table, I am displaying this json datas in table.

If i click that checkbox i want to delete that first object from json.

Output expected: (if i checked checkbox)

```
[
      { 
         field1: '123456789',
         field2: 'Mohamed',
         field3: 'Sameer',
         field4: 'Salai',
         field5: 'Salai',
         field6: 'Asia',
         field7: '111111',
         field8: '10-10-10',
         field9: 'mohd@if.com',
         field10: 'ifelse',
         field11: 'ifelse',
         field12: 'India',
         field13: 'test',
         field14: 'test',
         field15: 'test' 
      },
      { 
         field1: '123456789',
         field2: 'Hameed',
         field3: 'Basha',
         field4: 'Salai',
         field5: 'Salai',
         field6: 'Asia',
         field7: '600091',
         field8: '10-10-10',
         field9: 'hameed@gmail',
         field10: 'ifelse',
         field11: 'ifelse',
         field12: 'India',
         field13: 'test',
         field14: 'test',
         field15: 'test' 
      }
]
```

if user not checked i want that again first object from json.

My checkbox code:(Jade)

input(type='checkbox')

My UI:

[image]

Comment: add isDisplay=true flag with object. When you check checkbox make it false. And on client side use ng-show="isDisplay"

Comment: I dont want to just hide, i complete want to remove json, then only i can able to skip that object to insert into server side. is this possible?

Comment: is it working???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be helpful to you!.

```js
     var d=[
           { 
              field1: 'gsm',
              field2: 'firstname',
              field3: 'lastname',
              field4: 'street',
              field5: 'city',
              field6: 'region',
              field7: 'postcode',
              field8: 'dob',
              field9: 'email',
              field10: 'company',
              field11: 'url',
              field12: 'country',
              field13: 'data1',
              field14: 'data2',
              field15: 'data3' 
           },

           { 
              field1: '123456789',
              field2: 'Mohamed',
              field3: 'Sameer',
              field4: 'Salai',
              field5: 'Salai',
              field6: 'Asia',
              field7: '111111',
              field8: '10-10-10',
              field9: 'mohd@if.com',
              field10: 'ifelse',
              field11: 'ifelse',
              field12: 'India',
              field13: 'test',
              field14: 'test',
              field15: 'test' 
           },
           { 
              field1: '123456789',
              field2: 'Hameed',
              field3: 'Basha',
              field4: 'Salai',
              field5: 'Salai',
              field6: 'Asia',
              field7: '600091',
              field8: '10-10-10',
              field9: 'hameed@gmail',
              field10: 'ifelse',
              field11: 'ifelse',
              field12: 'India',
              field13: 'test',
              field14: 'test',
              field15: 'test' 
           }
        ];
        var temp={};
         var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
            app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
            $scope.data=d;
             
              $scope.checkbox_link=function(i){
                var ele=document.getElementById("checkbox_id");
                if(ele.checked==true){
                   if($scope.data.length>1){
                       temp=$scope.data[i];
                       $scope.data.splice(i,1);
                   }
                }else{                                   
                    $scope.data.splice(0,0,angular.copy(temp));
                   }
              }
            });
```

```css
 table{
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    }
```

```html
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
        <div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
        <input type="checkbox"  ng-click="checkbox_link(0)" id="checkbox_id"/> skip first row
        {{temp}}
          <table border="1">
            <tr ng-repeat="d in data">
              <td>{{$index+1}} </td>
              <td>{{d.field1}} </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: I need again if uncheck the checkbox :)

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
var data = [
   { 
      field1: 'gsm',
      field2: 'firstname',
      field3: 'lastname',
      field4: 'street',
      field5: 'city',
      field6: 'region',
      field7: 'postcode',
      field8: 'dob',
      field9: 'email',
      field10: 'company',
      field11: 'url',
      field12: 'country',
      field13: 'data1',
      field14: 'data2',
      field15: 'data3' 
   },

   { 
      field1: '123456789',
      field2: 'Mohamed',
      field3: 'Sameer',
      field4: 'Salai',
      field5: 'Salai',
      field6: 'Asia',
      field7: '111111',
      field8: '10-10-10',
      field9: 'mohd@if.com',
      field10: 'ifelse',
      field11: 'ifelse',
      field12: 'India',
      field13: 'test',
      field14: 'test',
      field15: 'test' 
   },
   { 
      field1: '123456789',
      field2: 'Hameed',
      field3: 'Basha',
      field4: 'Salai',
      field5: 'Salai',
      field6: 'Asia',
      field7: '600091',
      field8: '10-10-10',
      field9: 'hameed@gmail',
      field10: 'ifelse',
      field11: 'ifelse',
      field12: 'India',
      field13: 'test',
      field14: 'test',
      field15: 'test' 
   }
]
```

Then in your controller add function :

```
var deletedItem = [];
function onchangeCheckBox(isChecked) {
  if(isChecked && data.length > 0) {
    deletedItem = data.splice(0,1);
  } else if(deletedItem.length > 0 ){
    data.unshift(deletedItem[0]);
    deletedItem = [];
  }
}
```

And when you uncheck checkbox do this:

```
data.unshift(deletedItem);
deletedItem = {};
```

Comment: Will you post checkbox code? what i want to add near input(type='checkbox')

Comment: No its showing onChange is not defined? i want to use angularjs not jquery

Comment: Ok wait will do and tell.

Comment: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="confirmed" ng-change="onchangeCheckBox(confirmed)"  />

Comment: Post my jade code , update your answer it will be helpful :)

Comment: see my updated question i post the checkbox screenshot, if i have checkbox the skip first row checkbox i need to delete first object if not checked i need that first object.

Comment: yes, now attach ng-change event to this checkbox, and pass checkbox value to parameter, and call that function what i added to this answer.